# Summary Tag displaying "Details" instead of Text

Tags: html, css

So I've got two identical codes in one HTML file. One is working and displaying "Week one:", the other is displaying the tags name (Details). I cant really find any reason for this. The issue remains even If I am not using a style sheet. Is it a conflict between the tags?

```html
<hr>
<details class="eventsum">
  <summary class="eventsum-st">Week one:</summary><a name="w1" />
</details>

<hr>
<details class="eventsum">
  <summary class="eventsum-st">Week two:</summary><a name="w2" />
</details>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from the `<a> tag`, this one needs its closing tag in order to function properly, so just changing that will do the job :

```
<details class="eventsum">
    <summary class="eventsum-st">Week one:</summary>
    <a name="w1"></a>
</details>

<details class="eventsum">
    <summary class="eventsum-st">Week two:</summary>
    <a name="w2"></a>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the "a" tags before the details tag will resolve the issue

```
<hr><a name="w1"/>
<details class="eventsum"><summary class="eventsum-st">Week one:</summary>
</details>

<hr><a name="w2"/>
<details class="eventsum"><summary class="eventsum-st">Week two:</summary>
</details>
```

Comment: Note: Sometimes it might not solve the issue. This seems to occure when there are many <a> tags like those above. You will just need to break the tag up into <a> and </a> instead of <a/>